# Does Mongoose save fields/subdocuments that did not change?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a well-defined schema, in the sense that there are no `Mixed` fields that require `#markModified()`.

Per my understanding of the Mongoose docs, Mongoose should detect which fields/subdocuments changed, and only submit the modified fields for persistence among `update()`. Is this correct? Because it appears that Mongoose is submitting unmodified fields and subdocuments on update (or, eh, upsert) as well.

Comment: It shouldn't be, no.  Can you edit your question to include a specific example?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I should just answer/close the question because the answer is, as you said, "no". I just had something else going on.